# C# split into pre-allocated array changes array allocation

Tags: c#, .net-4.0

```
    static void TEST(string arg)
    {
        string[] aArgs = new String[3];
        aArgs = arg.Split(null,3);
    }
```

I had hoped that if `arg` has only two items, that `aArgs` would still have 3 elements after the `.Split`. However, it seems that `aArgs` gets forced to 2 elements if `.Split` finds 2.

How do I keep `aArgs` at 3 items, whether `.Split` has 3 or not.

Also, what's supposed to happen if `.Split` hands back more than 3 items?

Comment: You don't need to say "Context C#, .NET 4.0" since the question is tagged `C#` and `.net4.0`

Comment: Funny, your last question is something I'd expected to be asking in the comments. What do _you_ want to have happen if there are more than 3 items? Ignore them? EDIT: Have them rolled into the last item (which is the current behaviour)?

Comment: Split returns string array, and you have just re-assign your's aArgs variable, so it would be initialized with elements count which Split returns.

Comment: It's not changing the allocation.  String.Split() by definition returns an array object.  Therefore, it's reassigning, not reallocating.  Ultimately I suspect you already know the answer...you need custom logic.

Comment: @DonBoitnott: "...you need custom logic" ... that about sums it up!

Comment: @PhaDaPhunk: err ... umm ... yeah ... good point

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code will do what you ask for in your question...  any values past index 3 will be concatenated into the last value.

```
static void TEST(string arg)
{
    string[] aArgs = new String[3];
    string[] argSplit = arg.Split(null,3);
    argSplit.CopyTo(aArgs, 0);
}
```

Comment: Actually, any index values past 3 will be rolled into the last one: "asdf zxcv qw er ty" yields: `{"asdf", "zxcv", "qw er ty"}`

Comment: Good catch you are absolutely right.. editing answer to reflect it!

Answer (score 2):

How about this approach:

```
static void TEST(String arg)
{
    String[] mySA = SplitIntoArray(arg, 3, true);  //truncating in this case to force 3 returned items
}

String[] SplitIntoArray(String StringToSplit, Int32 ArraySize, Boolean Truncate)
{
    List<String> retList = new List<String>();
    String[] sa = StringToSplit.Split(null);
    if (sa.Length > ArraySize && Truncate)
    {
        for (Int32 i = 0; i < ArraySize; i++)
                retList.Add(sa[i]);
    }
    else
    {
        foreach (String s in sa)
            retList.Add(s);
    }

    return retList.ToArray();
}
```

This would also work nicely as a String extension method, with some minor modifications.

I guess you could also enhance it with the additional option of what to do with > ArraySize items...combine all into the last item, for instance, as would have been done by default.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what was the question intent, but if you want to avoid array allocation with `String.Split` method, you should use a custom code as suggested by @DonBoitnott :

```
var buffer = new string[3];
string testValue = "foo1;foo2;foo3;foo4;";
int count = Split(testValue, ';', buffer);
Debug.Assert(count == 3);
Debug.Assert(buffer[0] == "foo1" && buffer[1] == "foo2" && buffer[2] == "foo3;foo4;");


static int Split(string value, char separator, string[] buffer)
{
    if (value == null)
        return 0;
    if (buffer == null || buffer.Length == 0)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("buffer"); // or nameof(buffer) with c# 6 / .NET 4.6

    const int indexNotFound = -1;
    int bufferLength = buffer.Length;
    int startIndex = 0;
    int index;
    int nextBufferIndex = 0;
    while ((index = value.IndexOf(separator, startIndex)) != indexNotFound)
    {
        if (++nextBufferIndex == bufferLength)
        {
            buffer[nextBufferIndex-1] = value.Substring(startIndex);
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            buffer[nextBufferIndex-1] = value.Substring(startIndex, index - startIndex);
            startIndex = index + 1;
        }
    }
    if (nextBufferIndex<bufferLength && value.Length >= startIndex)
        buffer[nextBufferIndex++] = value.Substring(startIndex);

    return nextBufferIndex;
}
```

Note that each string in the pre-allocated array is a new string allocation (`String.Substring` allocates a new string).